# Calling C# webMethod in Objective C

Tags: c#, objective-c, http-post, httpresponse, webmethod

I'm trying to communicate with this simple C# webMethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string login(string userName)
{
     if (userName == "test"){
         return "validated";
     }
     return "error";
}
```

I'm trying to connect to it with the following Objective C code:

```
NSString *userName = @"test";
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userName=%@", userName];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSString *serverURLString = @"http://myURL.aspx/login";
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:serverURLString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"result = %@", result);
```

rather than printing out "validated" or "error", I get:

```
result = <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
</title></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="login" id="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"   value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZFwRG2UySOwu+02xaz+VP6mmD60UBRkXvHCHxGohOt9d" />
<div>    
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me if there is something obviously wrong with either the web method or the Objective C code? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebMethods are SOAP I believe, so rather than doing it manually why not use an API for handling SOAP? Such as [wsdl2objc](http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm just getting into Obj-C and had never heard of this API but if it makes the whole process simpler, it'll do for me. I'll go check it out.

Comment: I eventually got it working, although I'm not entirely sure how. IK think there was an error in the way the server had initially been set up. Nonetheless, I'll research wsdl2objc to see if it helps with the rest of the process so I'll accept this answer.